# How to Access Additional Parameter in j_spring_security_check and access in AuthenticationProvider

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

How can we get the Access to additional post param from front end in CustomAuthenticationProvider which extends DaoAuthenticationProvider.

Need to do logic implementation in my CustomAuthenticationProvider on the basic of additional check param while login using Spring authentication.

Thanks in Advance!!

Answer (score 0):

We need much more details to be able to give a complete answer. But here's the general idea:

- First, keep in mind that `AuthenticationProvider`s are (and should be kept) unaware of the web context. They are meant to validate an `Authentication` object and they can (and should) be run in a web app as in a EE or desktop app.
- You should create your own Authentication object (in that case a subclass of `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken`) that will hold your new/custom property, let's call it `CustomToken` with a new property `customProp` (you should really choose more meaningful names :) )
- You should subclass `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter` to be able to access the request params and put what you need in your Authentication object: the method `setDetails` in `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter` is meant exactly to that need, so just override that method in your subclass. Don't forget to configure that new subclass to be used in spring security config instead of `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter`
- In your CustomProvider you can now cast the authentication object to `CustomToken` and retrieve the added property (`customProp`) from that authentication object.

Comment: Thanks Hamdi for the Reply

Comment: More Detail :-  We have two tables where we are storing user details to check the credential and we have our own CustomAuthenticationProvider which extends DaoAuthenticationProvider. Now on the basic of the additional parameter provided from front end during authentication process , we need to decide the table to get the hash password to check.

Comment: Thanks for the details. The solution I suggested is perfectly applicable. Please tell me if something is not clear, or accept the answer otherwise.

Comment: Thanks Hamdi , I am able to do so.